# Samsung M2020 printer not working since 19.04 upgrade

Tags: drivers, upgrade, samsung, 19.04

I upgraded to 19.04 and cannot print on my samsung M2020 printer (network). I have tried to remove it from the list of installed printers for reinstall the driver but I can not do it. When I try to install the driver downloaded from hp (samsung) it says it's already installed. When I try to print system says additional drivers must be installed. How can I reinstall my printer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Samsung printers aren't HP. You probably need to reinstall the actual Samsung drivber.

Comment: Samsung printers are now supported by hp. Pease read my post, Iḿ having problems reinstalling the driver...

Comment: Please [edit] and post the link to the drivers you installed.

Answer (score 2):

1. add new repository

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

```
wget http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/pool/debian/extra/su/suldr-keyring_2_all.deb
```

```
sudo dpkg -i suldr-keyring_2_all.deb
```

```
sudo apt update
```

2. search your version

```
apt search suld-driver
```

(you cant find your version on this page by model number http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/supported.html )

3. install your driver

```
sudo apt install suld-driver-**RIGHTVERSION**
```

```
sudo apt install suld-configurator-2-qt4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to debug that. In my case (ML-1675) the printer just prints some error from it's internal processor when I print either from Ubuntu 19.04 or Fedora 30. So I assume it's some upstream CUPS or system libs regression. At the same time I was able to print on that printer on freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM. No problems there.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem with original drivers.
What helped me is installing alternative drivers for M2020 from https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

Just follow installation steps on the bchemnet website. After install is complete add your printer by clicking "Add..." button in Settings -> Devices -> Printer. You should be able to print now!
Hope it will help you :)